# Remote rejected to delete git remote branch

Tags: git, github

I am having an issue with a git remote branch that refuses to be deleted.

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003515/8869277), I have deleted my local branch with `git branch -d qa` without any issues, but when I run `git push --delete origin qa` to delete the remote branch I get the error:

`! [remote rejected]   qa (refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/qa)`

I get the same error when running `git push origin :qa`, and when I try to force the deletion with `git push --force origin :qa` or the variation of `git push origin --delete --force qa`.

Does anyone know to to force the deletion of the remote branch?

If it is relevant, I am running *git version 2.17.1*

Thanks!

#### Update:

The issue was that `qa` was set as the default branch. In my repository I went to `Settings > Branches > Default Branch` and changed it to master, which allowed me to run `git push --delete origin qa` with no errors.

Comment: Is `qa` your default branch? You'd know this by investigating the settings on your Github repo.

Comment: @JakeWorth yes it was - I changed it and was able to fix the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GitHub doesn't let you delete the default branch using Git.

You can either change the default branch to something else and then delete the `qa` branch, or you can [delete the branch using the API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#delete-a-reference).

Answer (score 0):

@bk2204 is correct that you are not allowed to delete the default branch on GitHub.

Instead, you need to go to the GitHub repository's **Settings** Page and select **Branches** tab on your left.

[image]

You then need to switch the default branch accordingly as illustrated on the above snapshot.

Thereafter you can run this command from Git

> git push  --delete

For example use `git push origin --delete main` to delete a branch named as ***main***

You will get this confirmation.

[image]